# non-array objects much have a [Symbol.iterator]() method Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, object

I am handling multiple TextInput props in a single handler, and my code works in an older version of react native. However, ever since the upgrade to 16.9 I have not been able to reuse that bit of code as I keep getting 'Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. non-array objects much have a Symbol.iterator method'

I have checked on here, but I have not been able to find a solution, below are my sample codes. I have trimmed the code down for better clarity

Input.js

```
  focus = () => this.refs.input.focus();

  _onFocus = () => this.props.onFocus(this.props.field);
  _onChange = value => this.props.onChange(this.props.field, value);

          <View style={s.inputWrapper}>
            <TextInput
              ref="input"
              {...additionalInputProps}
              keyboardType={keyboardType}
              autoCapitalise="words"
              returnKeyLabel='Done'
              returnKeyType='done'
              autoCorrect={false}
              style={[
                s.baseInputStyle,
                inputStyle,
                ((validColor && status === 'valid') ? { color: validColor } :
                (invalidColor && status === 'invalid') ? { color: invalidColor } :
                {}),
              ]}
              underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
              placeholderTextColor={placeholderColor}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              value={value}
              onFocus={this._onFocus}
              onChangeText={this._onChange}
              maxLength={maxLength}
            />
</View>
```

Card.js

```
    inputProps = field => {
      const {
        validColor, placeholders, values, status, onFocus, onChange, onBecomeEmpty,
        onBecomeValid, additionalInputsProps, } = this.props;

        return {
          validColor,
          ref: field,
          field,
          placeholder: placeholders[field],
          value: values[field],
          status: status[field],
          onFocus,
          onChange,
          onBecomeEmpty,
          onBecomeValid,
          additionalInputProps: additionalInputsProps[field],
        };
    };


        <Input
          {...this.inputProps('number')}
          keyboardType="numeric"
          label='Card Number'
          inputStyle={{ letterSpacing: 2 }}
          maxLength={22}
        />
```

Page.js

```
    handleCardChange = form => {
      console.log(form)
    };
    _onFocus = (field) => console.log('focusing', field);

                <Card
                  autoFocus
                  requiresName
                  requiresCVC
                  onChange={this.handleCardChange}
                  onFocus={this._onFocus}
                />
```

can some please help me make the code better, as what I have in Card.js does not work

Comment: you're going to need to create a reproducible runnable demo.  there isn't enough information to go on to even begin to guess the problem, (can't even guess which variable it doesn't like), and it's highly probable that the spread operator it is complaining about isn't even within the code you have here (which would be my first guess).  here's a few links you can look at to see if they help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991403/typeerror-invalid-attempt-to-spread-non-iterable-instance/53991545    https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10509

Comment: some other possibilities would be to provide what additionalInputProps looks like before it complains, and maybe this.inputProps, possibly the [field] access are throwing an error

Comment: thanks
I found my mistake and was able to solve it using lodash

Comment: you can post a solution describing the problem and then accept it to give this question closure