# How to add an newly fetched data to an existing array (Js, VueJs)

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have some pagination on an Api route which was used to fetch the post's data.

When the pagination is on page 2, I would like to add the fetched data from the page and add to the existing array.

**Function used to fetch the data**

```
const posts = ref([]);
const page = ref(1);

const getPosts = async (page) => {
        await axios
            .get("/api/explore/gallery/?page=" + page)
            .then((response) => {
                if (page === 1) {
                    posts.value = response.data;
                } else {
                    posts.value = { ...posts.value, ...response.data };
                }
            });
    };
```

> So when the page is 2 onward, the fetched data will add to the existing array.

**The result if I used `posts.value = { ...posts.value, ...response.data };`**

[image: The id start from 51 instead of 1 - 100.]

The `id` start from `51` instead of `1 - 100`.

I have also tried `posts.value = [ ...posts.value, ...response.data ];` but returned

```
PostApi.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
    at _nonIterableSpread (PostApi.js:12:39)
    at _toConsumableArray (PostApi.js:10:131)
    at eval (PostApi.js?c0c4:15:21)
```

**`response.data` look like this**

[image]

**`post.value` look like this**

[image]

Comment: An array uses `[ ... ]` not `{ ... }` Also, you need to make sure you're spreading the actual array, not something else. Why are you referring to `posts.value` is `posts` is an array? There's maybe a `posts[0].value` but an array does not have a `.value`

Comment: You can use the [concat method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to add value to the existing array : `posts.value = posts.value.concat(response.data)`

Comment: @ChrisG, i referred to this solution from other people https://stackoverflow.com/a/71110698/17737657

Comment: In other words, the loaded array is `response.data.data` and the existing array is `post.value.data`, which means you need `post.value.data = [ ...post.value.data, reponse.data.data ]`

Comment: @ChrisG, there is a value because i am using `Vue`'s `ref`

Comment: @RenaudC5, `concat` does not seem to be working.

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: posts.value.concat is not a function at eval (PostApi.js?c0c4:15:47`

Comment: @Chai Fuu Wong It seems like `ref` can't take an array as it's a mutable ref object, which has a single property value that points to the inner value. Try instantiate the array with `const post = {value: []}` or `const post = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution,

```
const getPosts = async (page) => {
    await axios
        .get("/api/explore/gallery/?page=" + page)
        .then((response) => {
            if (page === 1) {
                posts.value = response.data;
            } else {
                posts.value = {
                    ...posts.value,
                    data: [...posts.value.data, ...response.data.data],
                };
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: Glad it works, but consider this: often, the reason an api pages is because there's too much data for the client to handle all at once.  A client that navigates to too many pages might end up with too much data.  The simpler alternative is to just fetch on every page change, and cache at most one or two pages in each direction.

Comment: @danh, Thx for your suggestion, but maybe you can explain in more detail cuz I am not quick to understand.

Comment: @danh, what would be the best approach to handle things like infinite scroll to display the posts? currently, i am using pagination(laravel) in the backend and fetching them in the front end, and storing them in an array, as you can see above ? but like you said the client would end up getting much and much more data .

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a cache to provide more control over how much data accumulates on the client.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46432113/294949) provides a reasonable looking LRU cache.  Combining it with your api might look like this...

```
const cache = new LRU(8);

const getPosts = async (page) => {
    const result = cache.get(page);
    if (result) return Promise.resolve.result;
    return await axios
        .get("/api/explore/gallery/?page=" + page)
        .then((response) => {
            cache.set(page, response.data);
            return response.data;
        });
};
```

Your markup would show the current value of `posts`.  Whatever user event that triggers your paging would do this...

```
// in an async method
this.posts = await getPosts(pageComputedFromUI);
```

This would have about the same effect as your solution (which caches everything and never expels anything), but with the benefit of memory kept under your control -- and at the cost of more network requests.

Comment: maybe we should continue to discuss in pm, cuz I'm not sure if I implemented it correctly

Comment: https://discord.gg/Fx5GXYyq, here's a server for programmers to discuss or add me at discord `suprême_GuNz#9742`